# No columns and row info in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I split the data into the test and training set without using `train_test_split` 
My Function:

```
def split(X, y):
    arr_rand = np.random.rand(X.shape[0])
    split = arr_rand < np.percentile(arr_rand, 75)
    X_train = X[split]
    y_train = y[split]
    X_test =  X[~split]
    y_test = y[~split]

    #print (len(X_Train)), (len(y_Train)), (len(X_Test)), (len(y_Test))
    return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test
```

My problem is, when I output `X_train` I receive info that it has 76 rows x 8 columns. 
 However while printing  `X_test` this info is missing. This is how it looks like. My df is a csv file:
[image]

I needed to split it for X,y labels which I did with such approach: 
 `X, y = df.iloc[:,0:8], df.iloc[:,8:9]` 
 And later  `X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = split(X,y)`

This is the output why shape info is missing?

Resuls: [image]

Comment: What happens if you manually check the shape with `X_test.shape`?

Comment: @Darina Nothing, it returns (26, 8)

Comment: So your data frame is fine, it's just an error in Jupyter rendering. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When all the rows are shown in the result cell (in your example you have only 26 rows for X_test), the shape information is not shown. By default, the maximum number of rows shown is 60 (unless you change `pandas.options.display.max_rows`), so if `X_test` has less than 60 rows, the shape information is not shown.

Try `X_test.shape` to see the shape.

Comment: X_train.info gives me the columns and row values, but X_test.info does not.

Comment: In `X_test.info()` you have the number of rows (entries) in the second row of the message.